# Rejecting class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm because it failed compile-time verification

Tags: java, android, facebook, account-kit

I am getting this error while integrating facebook account kit for mobile verification

> Process: com.mobilefirst.pausepay, PID: 26532
>                                                                             java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm because it failed compile-time
>   verification (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm'
>   appears in /data/app/com.mobilefirst.pausepay-2/base.apk)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity.onCreate(AccountKitActivity.java:348)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Just add the following lines in gradle file:-

```
 compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
compile ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}

 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:+"
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
```